# XCode 4 - how to stop the download of documentation

Tags: ios, xcode4

I accidentally started the documentation download within XCode (not the one I wanted - of course). Is there any way stopping this huge download?

Comment: nope - there is an auto resume on the download

Comment: having a similar problem in xcode 7 beta. Removed the docsets (from ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/),  and was able to free up space on startup disk. But the download section in the preferences still shows the docs as installed, and again my disk has filled up in some time; Assuming its due to automatic download of documentation. But the checkbox for automatic update of documentation is not selected.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In XCode Preferences / Downloads tab, you can select whether it automatically downloads components and documentation.  You can also cancel the library downloads in flight.  [XCode 4.2]

Answer (score -2):

*no*. (**Edit**: You can *now* (Xcode 7.2 - certainly earlier, but not in summer of 2011) easily cancel it in *Preferences->Documentation*)

you can delete it once it's downloaded: Preferences->Documentation-[select doc set] click ^ on the bottom,

it will tell you where it's stored,

that will keep you from searching through useless information when you're searching the Docs.

Comment: hi bshirley, thanks for your response. Good to know that I can delete it. In fact I had to wait for the download to complete. :-) So no abort mechanism for the download.

Answer (score -3):

After disabling, you must restart xcode to stop the download

Comment: This does not answer the question but may better be suited as a comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: Not anymore by the looks of it. I just unchecked the documentation in the preferences have way through a download, and it stopped immediately